# distinct a field without case sensetive in Elasticsearsh

Tags: elasticsearch, distinct, case-sensitive

We have a requirement about distinct a field **without** case sensitive (for example “CIty” and “ciTy” must been in a group).
can i implement a query by this feature in **Elasticsearch** ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This problem needs to be resolved while indexing. Tokens can be converted to lowercase while indexing using [normalizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/normalizer.html)

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "city": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

will give

```
 "aggregations" : {
    "cities" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "a",
          "doc_count" : 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

both "A" and "a" are treated as single value